# Replacing a well pressure tank

Tags: plumbing, pump, well, water-tank

I have a 19 gallon pressure tank that appears to be waterlogged. When tapping the tank it sounds like it is completely full of water and when running the water in the house the pump cycles constantly. I've purchased a 44 gallon tank to replace the 19 gallon tank. There's 15 faucets in the house (counting sinks, toilets, outdoor faucets, washer, dishwasher...), 19 gallons seemed undersized for our usage. The existing tank doesn't have a cross assembly, the pressure switch is mounted on the side of pump. There doesn't appear to be any relief valve or check valve. The whole thing seems to be wrong.

[image: Well pump]
[image: Water tank]

This is the existing tank--it sits to the right of the pump. The softener is to the left of the pump. The pressure switch connects to that green line. Does this warrant replumbing so that there is a line from the pump to a cross assembly off the bottom of the tank? One that has a check valve, a relief valve, a drain, and a cut-off valve. Something like this

[image: Tank cross assembly]

Also, is PVC appropriate in this application?

It may be useful to know that I'm in southeastern North Carolina. This is all housed in a small pump house that stays above freezing in the winter.

Comment: you are asking about a well pressure tank ... then you post a picture, but you do not include the tank in the picture ... please add it

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A diagram of the whole setup would be really helpful. If you can't add another picture, then post the URL and someone will be along to edit it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I have seen an over pressure valve on a well system so that would not concern me. Is PVC the right plumbing? Yes PVC is fine many homes have PVC on the cold water lines and cpvc on the hot water lines. Newer pressure tanks usually have a bladder that holds the water with the air charge on the outside of the bladder, these tanks are much smaller than the old diphram style tanks. My preference is to install the biggest tank that I have room for this allows for a longer draw down before the pump kicks in and reduces pump cycles this usually extends the life of the pump and reduces power consumption ( pumps draw 3-7 times there running value on startup so less starts saves $).the check valve may be in the pump or a foot valve at the bottom of the well so you may not see it but if there was not one in the system your tank would back flow as soon as the pump quit running so I doubt that is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

That does not look like any well pressure tank I have seen. It looks like something else. Post pictures that include more of the installation so we can see just what is included in your system and how it is piped.

Comment: That tank looks exactly like my well pressure tank. I'm confident there are many variations of such a product.